# How can you print notification for when file is ready for download in Shiny?

Tags: shiny

in my server portion I have:

```
 output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("Scores", ".csv", sep= "")}, 
    content = function(file){
        write.csv(out1(), file, row.names = F)
    }    
  )
```

and a corresponding downloadButton in the ui. I normally use showNotification when I have an event to observe but this doesn't seem to work for output content. How can I print a message to the user once all code is run and the download is ready?

Thank you

Comment: You usually don't need this kind of structure in a Shiny app if you've used reactivity correctly.

Comment: Generally, such things are handled by using `req` function from shiny or using `eventRactive` where needed